# Code stopped working after upgrade to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios4, xamarin.ios, ios5

I had these two lines of code that worked in iOS 4. Following an upgrade to iOS 5, it no longer works.

The code would put a background image on the Navigation bar.

```
CGImage navban = CGImage.FromPNG(new CGDataProvider("images/banner.png"), null, false, CGColorRenderingIntent.Default);
NavigationController.NavigationBar.Layer.Contents = navban;
```

I am using MonoTouch. Does this no longer work in iOS 5? If so, is there another way to accomplish it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `BackgroundImageForBarMetrics` of `UINavigationBar` should do the trick. It's new in ios5 and supports this scenario without going behind UIKit's back.